# Is there a tool for test the Dedicated Server's bandwidth?

Tags: bandwidth

Is there a tool for test the Dedicated Server's bandwidth?

In the Switch I limited the Dedicated Server's port speed to 200M, but now I want to check whether the configuration is work.

How can I check it? is there an tool for checking the bandwidth?

I want to know the tools can test both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `speedtest-cli`, an unofficial command line client to popular network speed measurement website [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net)

Install using:

```
pip install speedtest-cli
```

Run speed test (with default options):

```
speedtest-cli
```

To see possible options:

```
speedtest-cli --help
```

Answer (score 0):

The free network speed testing tool **[iPerf3](https://iperf.fr/)** can benchmark the bandwidth.

You need two machines for testing.

On one machine ("server") the tool is started in server mode:

```
iperf3 -s
```

From another machine ("client") you can then measure the bandwidth, with *server* being the IP or name of the "server". The "client" must be able to connect to the corresponding port of the "server" (e.g. iperf3 default port 5201):

```
iperf3 -c server
```

Although you can measure against public servers listed at https://iperf.fr/iperf-servers.php, this will most likely not show you the maximum bandwidth of your setup. Anyway an example would be:

```
iperf3 -c bouygues.iperf.fr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one server, you can use `pv` and `netcat` to measure network speed:

On first:

```
nc -l -p 31337 < /dev/zero
```

On second:

```
nc IP_OF_FIRST_SERVER 31337 | pv > /dev/null
```

`31337` is example TCP port, you can change it.

Be aware that /dev/zero is easily compressible so using it for testing VPN speed will lead to incorrect results, as VPNs often use compression.